# Skype taking over urls

Tags: url, skype, phone-number

We have some issues in our application with skype taking over some of our urls, replacing them with a skype plug in that enables you to start calls. Looks like skype thinks they are phone numbers. I was wondering if there are some way to mark our urls such that skype doesn't think they are phone numbers?

Its described here http://www.skype.com/help/guides/ie_addon/, but no option for disabling this functionality in the html... Any suggestions? Would like to add an attribute to our anchor tags to tell skyp to stay away.

Comment: What do the links look like? and have you considered just removing the skype plugin from your browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

`<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />`

within your head element.

[link text](http://forum.skype.com/lofiversion/index.php/t78380.html)